# dusk can't assetSee its own ExampleTest

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I am new to dusk and I just installed dusk on a fresh laravel project.
when I enter php artisan:dusk I get the following error that says it can't see the text "Laravel" on "/" route despite the the fact that it is there.
And the browser doesn't open either.
Thanks in advance :)

```
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
PHPUnit 7.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:11633/devtools/browser/aee653fc-733b-4f2d-af35-5b347d1a497d
[0411/230433.674:INFO:CONSOLE(5496)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", source: http://localhost/dashboard/javascripts/all.js (5496)
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 6.62 seconds, Memory: 14.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Did not see expected text [Laravel] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\laravel\dusk\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\Concerns\MakesAssertions.php:173
C:\laravel\dusk\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\Concerns\MakesAssertions.php:144
C:\laravel\dusk\tests\Browser\ExampleTest.php:20
C:\laravel\dusk\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\Concerns\ProvidesBrowser.php:67
C:\laravel\dusk\tests\Browser\ExampleTest.php:21

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" I can't figure out where this error refers to? maybe it's the cause of the problem

Comment: What does the screenshot in `tests/Browser/screenshots` show?

Comment: *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"* tells you the truth. Check you `dashboard/javascripts/all.js` for excessive `}`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks man, I took a look at it and I realized I haven't entered port in .env file for APP_URL,so it was actually seeing this address :127.0.0.1,which was failing the test.

Comment: And for the browser problem I just commented --headless in driver() methid inside  DuskTestCase.php file ,but the browser doesn't persist,is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways you can try:

1.make sure copy ".env" rename ".env.dusk.local" and change APP_URL={http://localhost:8000} //you serve 2. run php artisan serve 3. run php artisan dusk Time: 2.17 seconds, Memory: 18.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
debug: 1.change DuskTestCase.php to see what website page you browse http://localhost:9515 , DesiredCapabilities::chrome()

2.add one line in your test file ExampleTest.php pause(1000)
all code refer to here: github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/488